# Wifi randomly goes down and does not turn on

Tags: wireless, 20.04

It sometimes happen that all of a sudden my wifi goes down. It stops scanning networks and says "No Networks". I know this has happened when my wifi show nothing besides its symbol.

[image]

When I do `ifconfig` after that happens, I can't find `wlp10s0f0` which is my wireless interface, in the list.

```
sudo ifconfig wlp10s0f0 up
```

returns

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Device or resource busy
```

Even

```
rfkill block wifi
rfkill unblock wifi
```

and

```
sudo services network-manager restart
```

doesn't help. A quick fix to this problem is restarting my PC. But that's just a temporary solution, and at times it is frustrating. Is there a permanent solution to this?

Output of `iwconfig`

```
wlp10s0f0  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

and `dmesg`

https://pastebin.com/YXMyrSzZ